# c++ string validation for user input

Tags: c++, validation, loops, cin

All I want to do, is prompt a user for a yes or no answer, and validate this to ensure they haven't typed something stupid.

I thought this would be a relatively straight forward task, however after many failed attempts at it myself, and looking around online, it seems everyone has a different opinion on the best way to do it.

**Pseudocode**

1. Ask question
2. prompt user
3. check if input = yes or input = no
4. if yes, do scenario a
5. in no, do scenario b
6. if invalid, return to point 2

**Code**

*main.cpp*

```
std::cout << "Do you have a user name? ("yes", "no"): ";
std::cin >> choice;
user.validation(choice);

if (choice == "yes")
{
// some code
}

if (choice == "no")
{
// some code
}
```

*User.cpp*

```
void User::validation(std::string choice)
{
    while (choice != "yes" && choice != "no")
    {       
        std::cout << "Error: Please enter 'yes' or 'no': ";
        std::cin >> choice;
        if (choice == "yes" && choice == "no")
        {
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

This works, up until they eventually type yes or no, when it jumps past if yes, and if no, straight onto the next part of the program

And I want to be able to call user.validation multiple times throughout the program to validate other yes/no questions

Comment: "I want to be able to call user.validation multiple times", what prevents you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not returning the corrected `choice` from `validation()`:

```
void User::validation(std::string &choice) // <-- insert a & here
```

Comment: Thanks @Phillip Kinkade so this appears, on the surface at least, to have fixed my problem, but what is better practice, to use std::string compare() or to pass by reference (which is what I think you have shown above).

Comment: I prefer using `==` over `std::string::compare()`.  Pass by reference is used a lot in C++.  It depends on the situation if it's better or not.

Comment: thanks, will definitely do some research and reading up in this area

Answer (score 3):

Try changing this

```
if (choice == "yes" && choice == "no")
```

For this

```
if (choice == "yes" || choice == "no")
```

Choice cannot be "yes" and "no" at the same time.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question!

Comment: Also changed this thanks, I thought it should be || not &&. but before I changed it to &choice as shown by @PhillipKinkade, || did not work at all for some reason

Answer (score -1):

C/C++ doesn't work like this for strings as the == operator isn't doing what you think it's doing for std::string objects and char* arrays.  Use the std::string compare() method instead.  Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/